# Serial Communication Between Arduino Mega and Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino

I am trying to connect my arduino Mega board to a Arduino Nano, I have connected them as follows:

```
MeAuriga | Nano
GND      | GND
TX       | RX
RX       | TX
```

The Mega is the receiver and the code is here:

```
char mystr[10]; //Initialized variable to store recieved data

void setup() {
  // Begin the Serial at 9600 Baud
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.readBytes(mystr,5); //Read the serial data and store in var
  Serial.println(mystr); //Print data on Serial Monitor
  delay(1000);
}
```

And the code for the Nano, which is the sender:

```
 char mystr[5] = "Hello"; //String data

    void setup() {
      // Begin the Serial at 9600 Baud
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop() {
      Serial.write(mystr,5); //Write the serial data
      delay(1000);
    }
```

**What Happens:**
When I connect them together on the nano, i just get prints of Hello on the serial monitor and it doesn’t matter if I disconnect cable it just keeps printing hello.

While the mega serial monitor is blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I changed Serial.readBytes to Serial1.readBytes, and I don't have my nano connected to USB, I am powering it from VIN. I only have the USB connected to the Mega. and i did connect the nano on pin 18 and 19

Comment: swap the roles and use Serial1 in Mega to receive or use SoftwareSerial in Nano. additionally remove the delay in the receiver code. the readBytes function will wait for a character a second

Comment: For Uno, study the example of [SoftwareSerial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample), and implement accordingly. For Mega, you don't need SoftwareSerial since it has more than one serial port. So you need to wire the Serial1 (i.e. pin 19 for Rx, and pin 18 for Tx) to Uno pins you are going to use as SoftwareSerial. And setup `Serail1.setup(9600)`, and use `Serial1.readBytes()` on Mega.

Comment: I added Serial1 to read and setup but i still get the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by starting the Serial for both.

**Mega**

```
char mystr[10]; //Initialized variable to store recieved data

void setup() {
  // Begin the Serial at 9600 Baud
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial1.readBytes(mystr,5); //Read the serial data and store in var
  Serial.println(mystr); //Print data on Serial Monitor
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
void loop() {
  Serial.readBytes(mystr,5); //Read the serial data and store in var
  Serial.println(mystr); //Print data on Serial Monitor
  delay(1000);
}
```

You don't have a serial monitor anymore!

If you use the RX/TX, you can't connect also your USB-cable as this is used to communicate with your Nano.

If you have 2 serial ports on your Arduino (the mega has 4):

```
        |COM|PIN RX|PIN TX|  
        | 0 |   0  |   1  |
        | 1 |  19  |  18  |
        | 2 |  17  |  16  |
        | 3 |  15  |  14  |
```

The `Serial` is used for your terminal (over USB cable) and the other 3 can be used to connect your Nano. Just write `Serial1.readBytes`, instead of `Serial.readBytes`.

If you don't have any serial port, you can use the `SoftwareSerial` library.

Comment: I tried using Serial1.readBytes and i also tried Serial2.readBytes, but the same problem is still occuring.

Comment: What did you changed? Just replace all Serial.* with Serial1.* is not the solution! You need to write Serial.print for the terminal and Serial1 for the communication with your Nano. And also on your Nano, YOU CAN NOT USE THE TERMINAL! If you want use the terminal on your Nano, you have to select another port to communicate with your Mega. It is not an I2C connection, on TX/RX you can not merge the bus with multiple devices. And do you connected the Nano to the Mega on the Pin 18 and 19? Or did you just changed the code?

Comment: I changed Serial.readBytes to Serial1.readBytes, and I don't have my nano connected to USB, i am powering it from VIN. I only have the USB connected to the Mega. and i did connect the nano on pin 18 and 19

Comment: If it still does not work, can you update the original post? It is easier to see what is wrong, instead of ask everything.